# OpenVPN conflicts with 3G mobile broadband

Tags: 11.04, networking, openvpn, 3g

I'm using ubuntu 11.04 2.6.38-8-generic fresh install.

The usb 3G dongle (Onda MT833UP) is recognised by the networkmanager and works fine until I install the openvpn client (`sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome`) ... obviously removing the opnvpn client is not an option ... any suggestion from anybody?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This started working after a kernel update :-)

I'm going to upgrade to 11.10 ... fingers crossed :-D